# handleChallenge() being trigger even handleSuccess() in mfp authentication

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mfp

Good day,

I have a mobile app that will call through mfp8 to my channel service.

In my front end angular code, I have create the `mfp securityCheckChallengHadler`, and call the `mfp login`, the following is my code of front end:

```
this.userLoginChallengeHandler = null;
        this.userLoginChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler(this.securityCheckName);
        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.securityCheckName = this.securityCheckName;
        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleSuccess = (loginSuccess) => {
            console.log("handleSuccess");
            this.isChallenged = false;
            if (this.currentEventHandler != this.eventHandler.success) {
                this.currentLoginGrantType = this.processLoginGrantType;

                //alert("initEventHandler|loginSuccess=\n" + JSON.stringify(loginSuccess));
                this.mfpAuthResponse = {
                    id: loginSuccess.id,
                    accessToken: loginSuccess.user.attributes.access_token,
                    tokenType: loginSuccess.user.attributes.token_type,
                    expiresIn: loginSuccess.user.attributes.expires_in,
                    scope: loginSuccess.user.attributes.scope,
                    clientId: loginSuccess.user.attributes.client_id
                };

            }
            this.currentEventHandler = this.eventHandler.success;
        };

        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleFailure = (loginError) => {
            console.log("handleFailure");
            this.isChallenged = false;
            if (this.currentEventHandler != this.eventHandler.failure) {
                this.authFailureEvent.emit(loginError);
            }
            this.currentEventHandler = this.eventHandler.failure;
        };

        this.userLoginChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = (challenge) => {
            console.log("handleChallenge");
            this.isChallenged = true;
            this.challengeResponseModel = challenge;
            this.authChallengeEvent.emit(challenge);
            this.currentEventHandler = this.eventHandler.challenge;
        };
```

And this is the part call the `WLAuthorizationManager.login(this.securityCheckName, authObj)`:

```
if (this.isChallenged) {
            console.log("mfp-performLogin|submitChallengeAnswer=");
            this.userLoginChallengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer(authObj);
        } else {
            console.log("mfp-performLogin|WLAuthorizationManager.login=");
            WLAuthorizationManager.login(this.securityCheckName, authObj).then(
                () => {
                    console.log("mfp-performLogin|WLAuthorizationManager.login.performed=" + performed + "\nmfpAuthResponse=\n" + JSON.stringify(this.mfpAuthResponse) + "\n\n");
                    if (!performed) {
                        this.ngZone.run(() => {
                            this.authSuccessEvent.emit(this.mfpAuthResponse);
                        });
                    }
                    performed = true;

                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log("mfp-performLogin|WLAuthorizationManager.login.err=\n\n" + JSON.stringify(err) + "\n");
                    console.log('wllogin err => ', err);
                    this.authFailureEvent.emit(err);
                }
            );
        }
```

During `WLAuthorizationManager.login(this.securityCheckName, authObj)`, I saw the `handleSuccess()` being  trigger, as my understanding, this is means my authentication with mfp is successful, and I can proceed to call any protected resource. However, not only `handleSuccess()`, I saw `handleChallenge()` being trigger as well.

And because of this, I cant get the `accessToken` value by calling the following mfp function, even the bad response also not show:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(userLoginChallengeHandler.securityCheckName).then(
    function (accessToken) {
        WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onSuccess");
        showProtectedDiv();
    },
    function (response) {
        WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        showLoginDiv();
});
```

However, everything will be smooth if I remove my scope-elements mapping and mandatory application scope in mfp console.

For your information, I keep seeing this in my mfp log:

```
[2/10/21 22:52:17:035 MYT] 00000289 p.server.security.internal.context.ClientSecurityContextImpl E FWLSE4054E: Failed to externalize the security checks. The security checks are deleted for client: bdfe187e-f881-4678-a65a-335de2f0a427
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.logging.Logger
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1131)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor501.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1577)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.context.SecurityChecksState.toExternalString(SecurityChecksState.java:114)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.context.SecurityChecksState.toExternalString(SecurityChecksState.java:29)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.context.ExternalState.buildDataItemFromCurrentState(ExternalState.java:90)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.context.ExternalState.store(ExternalState.java:68)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.context.ClientSecurityContextImpl.store(ClientSecurityContextImpl.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor276.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165.store(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.persistency.internal.transaction.StorageManagerImpl.storeLayer(StorageManagerImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.persistency.internal.transaction.StorageManagerImpl.doWithStorage(StorageManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.ibm.mfp.server.security.internal.rest.PreAuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(PreAuthorizationEndpoint.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor434.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1158)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to google for these, but cant get any answer, is it my configuration having some problem?

I tried to troubleshoot for this for weeks, but until now cant get any clue. Hope someone can help me please.

For your information, this is my scope element mapping from my mfp console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken(userLoginChallengeHandler.securityCheckName).then(
    function (accessToken) {
        WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onSuccess");
        showProtectedDiv();
    },
    function (response) {
        WL.Logger.debug("obtainAccessToken onFailure: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        showLoginDiv();
});
```

In the above API you are passing a scope which is name of your security check. If the client is already logged-in or is in the remembered state, the API triggers a success. If the client is not logged in, the security check sends back a challenge.

The reason why you see handleChallenge() function is being called because your user login success state has expired.  Handle the challenge accordingly and call submitChallengeAnswer() API to submit the answer when handleChallenge() function is called.

If you don't pass scope in WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken() API you won't be challenged even if login success state has expired

For more details read here : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/user-authentication/javascript/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have attach my Scope-Elements Mapping to my question. For obtainAccessToken(), I should pass in "push.mobileclient" right?
And `handleChallenge()` is being called immediately after `handleSuccess()` being called, suppose if `handleSuccess()` being called, then the success state should not expired so soon right? below 1 sec. How can I check what cause my login success state is expired? and trigger the `handleChallenge()`.
For your information, if I only put `push.mobileclient` in my scope element without security checks, then i wont see `handleChallenge()`.